# Child Package will not return to master once it has successfully completed

Tags: ssis

[image]
Within a Master SSIS Package I have two Execute Package Tasks which call two child packages - when then initial Script Task completes, and each Execute Package task is called they run in parallel - however one each of those packages completes successfully the process stops and does not return to execute the third stage of the SSIS Master_Package.dtsx.  Because both Execute Package tasks complete successfully there is no error message given.

I thought that this would happen automatically - is there a configuration setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I need to use a Sequence Container to house the two execute package tasks in order to fix this problem